# perl equivalent of python array.array(typecode, ..)

Tags: python, arrays, perl, types

I am trying to translate a python script to perl but currently stuck at couple of code snipets.

For instance how to write following python code in perl? (without using any perl array related packages)

```
# packet here is a binary string
data = array.array( 'h', ( ord( packet[i] ) for i in range( start, end ) ) )
FILE.write(data);
```

My (failed) attempt:

```
my @data;
foreach $i ( $start .. $end ) {
   $data[$i] = ord( substr( $packet, $i, 1) );  # Assuming that perl's ord = python's ord
}

print FILE @data;
```

---

**@ysth**, the actual input is a large binary file and in excitment of posting my first question here I forgot to generate a sample input and ouput, sorry about that. For completeness find below the sample input and output.

input:  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']  #think this as packet contents, start=0, end=4

ouput in python:

```
> cat py.out | xxd
0000000: 6100 6200 6300 6400                      a.b.c.d.
```

output in perl:

```
> cat pl.out | xxd
0000000: 3937 3938 3939 3130 30                   979899100
```

---

**@Pedro Silva**, As I understand in first line of your suggestion you just replace for loop with map functionality, the effect is same.
The unpack 'W*' returns error as W is not a valid type (perl 5.8.8).

Comment: As always with "how to write language X code in language Y", if you provide actual sample input and output, you allow people who only know language Y to answer; without, you are restricting yourself to answers from people who know both languages

Comment: In what way was your attempt a failure?

Comment: @LovelyVirus: I guess that was added in a later version; it stands for unsigned char value (which can be greater than 255, otherwise you can use `C`, which only works up to 8bit). My point with `unpack` was that, since you mention `$packet` is a binary string, you might want to consider `unpack` if the data is not simple `uchars`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**edit**

You need to clarify what you're saying. On my python (2.7.2), this is wrong:

```
FILE.write(data)
```

because `data` needs to be a string. I think what you mean to say instead is:

```
data.tofile(FILE)
```

Anyway, is this what you want?

```
print pack("s*", unpack("C*", "abcd"))
# piped through xxd => 0000000: 6100 6200 6300 6400     a.b.c.d.
```

Have a look through `perldoc -f pack` for the correct template string to use. Since you don't have access to `W` (unsigned wchar), i'm using `C` (unsigned char). `s` is a signed short (corresponding to python's `h`.)

**/edit**

There are no typed arrays in Perl. `ord` returns the numeric value of the *first* character of its argument.

Assuming this is what you want, just map the list resulting from splitting `$packet` on each character to `@data`, transforming each element with `ord` (the argument `$_` is implicitly given.)

```
my @data = map { ord } split //, $packet; # or
my @data = unpack 'W*', $packet;
```

Optionally, using a range different from the actual lower and upper bounds on `$packet`:

```
(split //, $packet)[$start .. $end];    # or
 split //, substr $packet, $start, $end # ysth's version
```

Comment: or `split(//, substr($packet, $start, $end))`

Comment: @Pedro Silva, FILE.write(data) is working in my tests (implicit conversion to string?). Anyway the pack/unpack suggestion is promising (as tested for dummy data). I'll test it on actuall data and will update here. As for 'W' option I believe I have it in my version of perl back in home. Will try that as well. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the hints Pedro. With pack/unpack one can mimic array.array(typecode, ...) functionality. As for FILE.write(array), it appears that array.tostring() is called implicitly...